# How can i return an error to std::filesystem?

Tags: c++, exception, c++17, std-filesystem

For example, this is how I do it using runtime_error

```
#include <exception>
#include <filesystem>

std::exception &foo(){
    try {
        if(!std::filesystem::is_directory(std::filesystem::path("sdfsdf"))){
            throw std::runtime_error("Error14");
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        return e;
    }
}

int main(){
    foo().what();
    // then i do smth with this error
}
```

how to do something similar, but with errors returning from std :: filesystem, I mean

```
std::filesystem::filesystem_error
```

I have tried this->

```
#include <filesystem>
std::filesystem::filesystem_error &foo()
{
    try {
        if(!std::filesystem::is_directory(std::filesystem::path("sdfsdf"))){
            throw std::filesystem::filesystem_error("ERROR14", std::error_code());
        }
    }
    catch (std::filesystem::filesystem_error &e) {
         // if (e.code == success)
        {
            return e;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

How to return such 'e' if there is no exception(i mean throw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::filesystem::is_directory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_directory) has a few overloads. If you provide an `std::error_code` object as the last argument it will ***not*** throw, but instead set the value of the error code object if an operating system error occurs. So you could use this overload to set the `std::error_code` object and create the `std::filesystem::filesystem_error` from it:

```
std::filesystem::filesystem_error foo()
{
    std::error_code err{};
    if (!std::filesystem::is_directory(std::filesystem::path("sdfsdf"), err))
    {
        return std::filesystem::filesystem_error{ "ERROR14", err };
    }

    return std::filesystem::filesystem_error{ "SUCCESS", err };
}
```

Note that this is returning by value; if you return by reference it will be a reference to a local variable that is destroyed after the function returns, and use of such a dangling reference would lead to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

[CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/filesystem_error/filesystem_error) documents the constructors for `std::filesystem::filesystem_error`.

Just use one of them:

```
throw std::filesystem::filesystem_error("Error14", std::error_code());
```

You'll probably want to put in a better message and error code :-)